# Use of set() and list comprehension

Tags: python, set

I am a beginner in Python. I would like to perform the following code but using set() intersection and list comprehension instead:

```
layers = []
for layer in wms.contents:
    if 'EPSG:900913' in wms[layer].crsOptions or 'EPSG:3857' in wms[layer].crsOptions:
        instance = WMSLayer(wms=wmsInstance, layer_name=str(layer))
        layers.append(instance)
```

The aim of this, is to loop in an object list `wms.content`, and create `WMSLayer` instance and put it into a list if one of the two strings (`'EPSG:900913' or 'EPSG:3857'`) are in `wms[layer].crsOptions` which is a list of strings.

The output would be a list of `WMSLayer` object.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: And what output do you expect from this then?

Comment: A list of WMSLayer objects

Comment: I think its clear enough now as the answer below is really close to what im looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
layers = [
    WMSLayer(wms=wmsInstance, layer_name=str(layer))
    for layer in wms.contents
    if {'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:3857'}.intersection(wms[layer].crsOptions)
]
```

Comment: is it normal that the output is a tuple or a list of tuple? Im trying to print items in the list but got `'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: tuple, no... list of tuple, quite likely. It's a list of whatever a WMSLayer returns.

Comment: Is it possible to get a list of WMSLayer object?